# Best ML approach for anomely detection on structured text data

Tags: neural-networks, classification, clustering, supervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I need help trying to understand what ML algorithm (or at least family of algorithms) would be best for my problem. There seem to be a great many different approaches and no clear explanations of what to use when.

My dataset is about 5k structured json documents which represent user created requests for "work". Each document is about 200kb in size. The values are mostly text labels.
I also have a sql db that tracked the status of those requests. So this tells me if the requests were a success or failure and in the case of failures I can identify which sub-modules in our system failed.
Of the dataset, about 10% of tasks resulted in a failure. I estimate that about half of those were due to wrong user input in the work document and the other half were due to issues in our code/environment.

I would like to train a model that will be able to predict (anomaly detection?) if a given document is likely to result in failure or not so we can warn the user before he submits it.

Which ML approach would you recommend? Are there any specific libraries that already implement this (Python, Node, AWS)?

Thank you, very much.
Pavel

Comment: With 10% failure rate you may be able to treat this as a classification problem, for which there are more resources out there. Once you got that working, and especially with good feature representation, then you can add anomaly detection to that